# How do i overlay frame number on video in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, overlay, frame

How do i watermarking a video with the current frame number?
My command is
[  ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4  ]

when I run this command in the terminal I executed my task successfully. but when I used this command in IDE (pycharm) it treated text='%{**frame_num**} as a variable IDE throws an error and when i replace **frame_num** with 1 or 0 or any number then IDE executed my code and make a video but this video has no watermark of the current frame number.

what should I do ??

```
import os

cmd =f'''ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4'''

print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: remove prefix `f` and it will treat it as normal text - `cmd = '''....'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove prefix `f` to have normal text instead of `f-string`

```
cmd = '''ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4'''
```

or you have to use double `{{ }}` in `f-string`

```
cmd = f'''ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{{frame_num}}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4'''
```